# exchange “globally” and “future” in temporal logic

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I cannot prove the following theorem given in Schneider's “On Concurrent Programming” as (3.16e):

> $$\Diamond\Box P \to \Box\Diamond P$$

I was given $$\begin{align}
\Box P & \to P\\
\Box P & \to \Box\Box P \\
\Box(P\to Q) & \to (\Box P \to \Box Q)\\
P & \vdash \Box P \\
\Diamond P & := \lnot\Box\lnot P
\end{align}$$

I deduced that I can prove (3.16e) from $$\Diamond\Box P \to \Box(\Box P \lor \Diamond\Box P)$$ which means “Suppose that $\Box P$ occurs at $t$. If we reached $t$, then $\Box P$, else $\Diamond\Box P$.”. I will appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 2):

It is unprovable in the given theory. There is a Kripke frame $\langle\{0, 1, 2\}, \operatorname{preorder\_cl}(\{\langle 0, 1\rangle, \langle 0, 2\rangle\})\rangle$ (“preorder_cl” is preorder closure aka reflexive transitive closure) that satisfies the given theory and does not satisfy (3.16e). A Kripke frame satisfies (3.16e) iff it is confluent, see [Wikipedia/Kripke_semantics#Correspondence_and_completeness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics#Correspondence_and_completeness). The Kripke frame $\langle\mathbb{N}, \leq\rangle$ used in linear-time temporal logic is confluent.

Comment: You're right that using those axioms alone, you can't prove this, but the text [does present 3.16e as a theorem](http://books.google.com/books?id=O0_5uT5vKigC&lpg=PA63&ots=bf_4_acs_A&dq=On%20Concurrent%20Programming%203.16e&pg=PA63#v=onepage&q=On%20Concurrent%20Programming%203.16e&f=false), so I wonder whether the text includes another axiom somewhere?  The axioms that you have describe the modal logic T (also called M).

Comment: Ah, the earlier pages describe that the semantics being used are anchored sequences, so the 3.16e is satisfied in every model, so $\models \Diamond\Box P \to \Box\Diamond P$, but without some additional proof machinery you don't have $\vdash \Diamond\Box P \to \Box\Diamond P$.

Comment: @Joshua Taylor: If the text includes other axioms, I didn't find them. It also includes $\Box \Box P \leftrightarrow \Box P$ as a theorem 3.18a, so I do not hope much.